# App Store Connect: Your app "Application" has one or more issues

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, production, xcode10, ios12

[Error after uploading IPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icss3.png)

[Message received from Apple in AppStore Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0vOs.png)

i tried to validate but got this error

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   "Application". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

But there is nothing in attachments, No issues listed no screenshots,
When i upload via Application Loader and it's successfully uploaded Itunes send email immediately with this Error

Solved: So my submission is finally working. For me, for some reason, I had "i386" as an architecture in the watch extension. Changing that to "arm64_32 and armv7k" to match the watch app solved the issue.

Comment: This is the only message from Apple **We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Application". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.?**

Comment: As i can see they informed **Please correct the following issues, then upload again** so please update your question with issues so other can help you.

Comment: after upload app 1 hours to remove this message. automatically.

Comment: Actually we can't told you the exact error where it is, because this is common. Try to upload through Organiser, before upload validaTE IT

Comment: Share the screenshot of page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..yeah this is the only response from Apple " We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Application". Please correct the following issues, then upload again"

Comment: I tried with to upload via Xcode and Application Loader also but got the same response each time

Comment: So my submission is finally working. For me, for some reason I had "i386" as an architecture in the watch extension. Changing that to "arm64_32 and armv7k" to match the watch app solved the issue.